# Folding recursive type family

Tags: haskell, type-families, data-kinds

I'm trying to fold a data with a phantom type of kind [*]. Here is simplified version of my code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

module Stack where
import Data.HList
import Data.Foldable as F

data T (a :: [*]) = T (Tagged a String)
(!++!) :: T a -> T b -> T (HAppendList a b)
(T a) !++! (T b) = T (Tagged (untag a ++ untag b))


a = T (Tagged "1") :: T '[Int]
b = T (Tagged "-- ") :: T '[]
ab = a !++! b :: T '[Int]
```

I would like a fold operator

```
(!++*) :: (Foldable t ) =>  T a -> t (T '[]) -> T a
a !++* t = F.foldl (!++!) a t
```

But that doesn't work. The compiler that `a` and `HAppendList a '[]` are different, even though they are not.

Why can't the compile unify `HAppendList a '[]` and `a` ?

(I can't do the fold manually in ghci though `:t a !++! b !++! b !++! b => T '[Int]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the definition of `HAppendList`:

```
type family HAppendList (l1 :: [k]) (l2 :: [k]) :: [k]
type instance HAppendList '[] l = l
type instance HAppendList (e ': l) l' = e ': HAppendList l l'
```

You and I know that `[]` is the left and right identity of `++`, but the compiler is only aware of the left identity:

```
happend' :: T a -> T b -> T (HAppendList a b)
happend' (T (Tagged a)) (T (Tagged b)) = (T (Tagged (a++b)))

-- Doesn't typecheck 
leftIdentity' :: T a -> T '[] -> T a 
leftIdentity' x y = happend' x y 

rightIdentity' :: T '[] -> T a -> T a 
rightIdentity' x y = happend' x y
```

You would need to have

```
type instance HAppendList '[] l = l
type instance HAppendList l '[] = l
type instance HAppendList (e ': l) l' = e ': HAppendList l l'
```

to have the compiler know about left and right identity; but these would be overlapping, so it doesn't type check. You can just flip the arguements, however:

```
(!+++!) :: T a -> T b -> T (HAppendList a b) 
(!+++!) (T (Tagged x)) (T (Tagged y)) = T (Tagged (y ++ x))

(!++*) :: Foldable t => T a -> t (T '[]) -> T a
a !++* t = F.foldl (flip (!+++!)) a t
```

With closed type families introduced in ghc 7.8, you can fix this problem:

```
type family (++) (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) :: [k] where 
  '[] ++ x = x
  x ++ '[] = x
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)

happend :: T a -> T b -> T (a ++ b)
happend (T (Tagged a)) (T (Tagged b)) = (T (Tagged (a++b)))

leftIdentity :: T a -> T '[] -> T a 
leftIdentity x y = happend x y 

rightIdentity :: T '[] -> T a -> T a 
rightIdentity x y = happend x y
```